# Animated Real-Time Graph Library

Tags: javascript, graph

Looking to create some visualizations of our server infrastructure and nerdy IT data. Want to do animated graphs that scroll from right to left in real-time, no page refreshes. Any good HTML5 canvas libraries to do such things?

Prefer a JS library. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/) or this [link](http://nme.pl/en/2011/01/real-time-graph-using-javascript).

Also, you can do it yourself: Flot jQuery Plugin or Google Chart API, coupled with jQuery-UI and jQuery AJAX you can do your real-time graph.

Answer (score 0):

i've had a very pleasant experience with [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/).

Comment: How is HighCharts?  I've taken a look at it and for static graphs it looks pretty awesome.  But I need (like the question proposer) a real time scrolling over the x-axis (time) graph....that I can zoom into and out of the time frame...so like 60 seconds or 15 mins or 1 hour for choices.  I was planning on using some jquery, html5 canvas to draw from point to point and so on.  It seems like a monumental task but fun.  If highcharts can do something similar...then from a timeframe aspect it would be a good choice.